# Eclipse PTP: NullPointerException when enable uploading rules

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a MPI application and I want to upload input data files before my application starts. I completed the Synchronize tab as specified in [Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2F03pLaunchConfig.html).

I then run my application and get an error: `An internal error occurred during: "Launching myapp".java.lang.NullPointerException`. I tried different settings but still can't get it works.

Does anyone experience the same problem? How can I fix it?

I use Eclipse Juno, with PTP v1.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I had ssh/ssh-server installed.

Thanks!